# Django Rest Framework organizing ViewSets and Routers

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Hi there so my question is probably about best practices when organizing ViewSets and the corresponding Routers in Django Rest Framework.

According to the official documentation, the routers should be stored in the `urls.py` and the viewsets should be stored in `views.py`.

My idea of an approach would be having the viewsets in a separate file like for example `viewsets.py` so that we don't end up mixing the normal Django views and the DRF Viewsets in the same file, improving readability.

The same would go for the routers where we would creaate a file called `routers` inside each app and register then with the main Default router instance.

These are my thoughts, but i am not sure how to:

1º Do this the proper way (the registering of the viewsets routers and all, should i place DefaultROuter in the `__init__.py` ?)

2º Is there a better approach?

Basically i want to separate the logic per app and inside each app separate by django views and DRf viewsets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what it's worth, I've always created a separate api/ subdirectory within my Django apps to hold all Django REST Framework related files.  This is just one way of doing things but it's helped keep separation of concerns within our applications.

The hierarchy looked like this...

- Django Project/

  - Django App/

    - views.py
    - models.py
    - urls.py
    - api/

      - serializers.py
      - viewsets.py

Comment: i like the idea. where and how are you adding the new routes?

Comment: I've actually always kept my routers within the root urlconf file because I consider my API urls to be at root level, but I can see the argument for keeping the separation.  If we follow the standard API naming convention /api/v1/resource/, then you pretty much get stuck putting your routers at root level.  If you'd like to keep them isolated, I'm guessing throwing a namespace in the URL could work /djangoapp/api/v1/resource/.  In the root urlconf just include yourdjangoapp.api.urls for /djangoapp/.

Comment: i was able to do that without directly using the urls.py like i specified here:
https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/2136