# Django database routing file location

Tags: python-3.x, routes, django-1.9

The Django project I'm currently working on requires that I use a database router. However, the [docs page on multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/multi-db/) doesn't specify whether a router should be defined [in a routers.py file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988432/how-to-use-db-router-in-django-1-4) or if it should be [stored in urls.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27129642/django-rest-framework-organizing-viewsets-and-routers) instead.

I've been finding a lot of conflicting information on this, especially when it comes to [best practices](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-best-practices-for-Django-development) (there are a lot of [different sources](http://www.slideshare.net/DZPM/12-tips-on-django-best-practices), and none of them talk about database routers).

So I'd like to know: where should my database routers *actually* be declared, and if this is in a separate file, where within my project should this file live (or does it even matter)?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

In the application directory. Using the Django tutorial as an example, polls/routers.py

```
mysite/
manage.py
mysite/
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
polls/
__init__.py
admin.py
apps.py
migrations/
    __init__.py
models.py
tests.py
views.py
routers.py
```